# My iOS device is not found while testing an app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, xcode5

I created a new project and I connected my iPhone to Mac. It is showing only iOS simulator list but it not showing any iOS device.

Comment: Check Deployment target of your project. If target is higher then device iOS, this will happens.

Comment: But it is showing in another project downmloaded from net, which is my device name.

Comment: its just because of Deployment target.

Comment: It's showing now ,thank you OMK,good answer from you

Comment: check your Provision bundle Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUst for officially.

As already you got the answer by the comments:

Here just posting it for someone will get useful , other than the problem of yours.

1. Check Deployment target of your project.

   [image]
2. Check the Architecture :[image]
3. Check whether the `Device is enabled for Development` .
4. `Device Added to portal & also imported the Provisioning Profile` into the XCODE

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Bundle Identifier in your Project and also you have provisional profile from get Apple

[image]